# Save return value from a function in one of its own parameters

Tags: shell, variable, function

This is what I want to achieve:

Function:

```
Func1() {
   $1="Hello World"
}
```

Call function:

```
local var1
Func1 var1
echo $var1  (should echo Hello World)
```

I found this example which seems to work, but I guess using eval is not a good idea:

```
Func1() {
   eval $1=$str1
}
```

How would be the correct way of doing this?

I'm coming from .Net and often use a parameter as a reference. For example, assigning a value back to the parameter which then can be used later on.

In the above example var1 should be assigned "Hello World"

(I'm using sh shell)

Comment: In `bash`, you could use variable indirection instead..

Comment: what are you trying to achieve with this?  are you just experimenting to see what it does? or do you have some purpose in mind?  if the latter, then see http://xyproblem.info/ - my brain's a bit dull and tired at the moment, but i can't think of any use for this that can't be done better in several different ways.

Comment: I just ran into a function with this design and I liked it.
I was not able to dig deeper in how it was achieved....so I just go curious (I'm new to Linux shell and learning)

Comment: @MrCalvin:  If you just saw an example using it, you could always use it but it's not a good idea.  Neither is using `eval` which **most often** leads to unexpected errors and security issues.

Comment: Just change my example code, I hope it's more clear now.

Comment: It's an interesting design approach, but one that isn't really used in shell scripting. If you were to use this approach in a professional environment I would say that it's likely that other people would find your code far harder to maintain. A more usual approach is to return a singleton value via _stdout_ (e.g. `result=$(someFunction with parameters)`) or to assign to globals. (Ugh, yes.)

Comment: Note that there's no `local` in standard _POSIX_ `sh` syntax (though there is in standard _Debian_ `sh` syntax).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`eval` is fine if you use it properly:

```
Func1() {
  eval "$1=\$str1"
}
```

Is safe as long as `Func1` is only called with the variable names you intend it to be passed.

As always, you need to quote your variables. And here, `$str1` doesn't need to be expanded before being passed to `eval`.

If `Func1` may be passed arbitrary strings that are not under your control, then that's where you'd get issues with values like `reboot;foo` and need to sanitize it like:

```
Func1() {
  case $1 in
    "" |\
    *[!abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789_]* |\
    [0123456789]* |\
    BASH* | LD_* | PATH | IFS | ENV | SHELLOPTS | PERL5LIB | PYTHON_PATH |...)
      echo >&2 "Can't set that variable"
      return 1
  esac
  eval "$1=\$str1"
}
```

Coming up with a complete list of *problematic* variables is a doomed task though.